# NoClassDefFound error from Java program in UNIX

Tags: java, javac

I executing a Java class in Unix. The Java program that I am executing is a JDBC program connecting to SQL Server. I have the class file but when executing "Java" command I get this error. Below are the commands.

```
>cd /home/test

>ls 

JDBCConnection.class  JDBCConnection.java   jtds-1.2.5.jar
```

Running the below command gives me "NoClassDedFound" error.

```
java -cp jtds-1.2.5.jar JDBCConnection
```

Error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JDBCConnection

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the current directory to the classpath

```
 java -cp .:jtds-1.2.5.jar JDBCConnection
```

Answer (score 1):

NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available during compile time.

In your case, you have not added the **current directory to the classpath** which holds the JDBCConnection.class classfile.

Try this out :

```
java -cp jtds-1.2.5.jar:. JDBCConnection
```

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html#ixzz2jxtG7mt5

Answer (score 0):

Add `.` to the classpath:

```
java -cp jtds-1.2.5.jar -cp . JDBCConnection
```